# Make UIButton Image right aligned using constraint in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm trying to set Image to right side using constraints. I'm using this code to achieve this:

```
  class func SetImageToRight(button: UIButton) {
        button.imageView?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
        button.imageView?.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        button.imageView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: button.imageView!.frame.width).isActive = true

        button.imageView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
```

But the problem is when there is any text inside UIButton image is right aligned but if button text is empty image is getting left aligned.

**Button without any text:**
[image: Button without any text]

**Button with text:**
[image: Button with text]

**I want image inside UIButton to be extreme right side of button no matter what is the size of button or if it has text or not.**

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the button has intrinsic size so according to it's size the trailing attached imageView will be shown , so when it's empty , size is zero the image it shifted left by trailing of button - 8 , and when it's not empty it shifted right , so either you set a static width for the button inside the view that holds it and the imageView

```
 button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.superview?.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8, constant: 0)
```

Or hook the button's imageView to the button's superview trailing

```
button.imageView?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.superView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, but I have tried this, but its not working.

Comment: I'm not setting button width, I have given constraints, so that it will get adjusted automatically.

Comment: yes but imageView attached to it so when it's empty it shift to left

Comment: so hook the imageView to that view with black border or give the button a width so then it's empty imageView is steady

Comment: Exactly, is there any way to make that image view right aligned?

Comment: see edit either give the button a steady width or hook the imageView to the buttons superview

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly a clean answer but it's also sometimes nicer to design a button with a UIView and overlay a clear button with constraints at `0, 0, 0, 0`.